# How can I use other DTO to reduce the if statements in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How Can I reduce the number of if statements in the below code in spring-boot.

The value is set in DTO by calling functions in service class.

```
public ResponseEntity<somedTO> fetchAlldata(@RequestParam(value="meta", required=false)
                                                    List<String> meta) {
    somedTO response = new somedTO();
    //Checks if param present else print complete service
    if (meta != null && !meta.isEmpty()) {
        if (meta.contains("A")) {
            response.setA(service.getA());
        }
        if (meta.contains("B")) {
            response.setB(service.getB());
        }
        if (meta.contains("C")) {
            response.setC(service.getC());
        }
        if (meta.contains("D")) {
            response.setD(service.getD());
        }
        if (meta.contains("E")) {
            response.setE(service.getE());
        }
        if (meta.contains("F")) {
            response.setF(service.getF());
        }
        if (meta.contains("G")) {
            response.setG(service.getG());
        }
    }
}
```

how can I proceed to use a DTO or Map to reduce the If statements?

Comment: how do you mean? do you think by putting code in another class, all of the sudden the conditions won't have to be checked anymore?

Comment: ryt i want to check based on param i want set the DTO Values

Comment: @venkateshp This could be done with a `Map`, but it would involve much more code and make all unreadable (= hardly maintainable). Your current solution is much simpler and clear to read.

Comment: Use switch case

Comment: But I need to reduce the If statements. probably using map

Comment: simply do this in dto instead of doing in service

Comment: you can try using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can put like this:

```
if (meta != null && !meta.isEmpty()) {
       meta.contains("A") ? response.setA(service.getA()) : 
meta.contains("environment") ? response.setB(service.getB()) : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class of DTO e.g somedToDTO
In this class add all these Strings you are using

```
Class somedToDTO{
    //Variable here
    //Setter, getters
    //Condition Check for meta
    //hash, toString() etc.
}
```

Then in service class pass dto object like:

```
public ResponseEntity<somedTO> fetchAlldata(@Valid @RequestBody somedToDTO metaDto)
{
     if(//check for is empty and null)
     {
         //return dto resposnse after condition check method
     }
}
```

This is how I code............

Answer (score 0):

I would advice the usage of a [Chain-of-responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern. Implement a set of handler, one for every if-statement you have, so you wrap every one of them in a class and 
define an executor class that calls all of those handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using reflection:

```
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    somedTO response = new somedTO;
    getAllFields(fields,somedTO.class);
    fields.stream().filter(field -> meta.contains(field.getName()))
                   .forEach(field -> {
        try{
            Field temp = service.getClass().getDeclaredField(field.getName());
            temp.setAccessible(true);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(response,temp.get(service));
        }catch (Exception ex){
        }
    });
```

Get field list method:

```
public static List<Field> getAllFields(List<Field> fields, Class<?> type) {
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(type.getDeclaredFields()));

    if (type.getSuperclass() != null) {
        getAllFields(fields, type.getSuperclass());
    }
    return fields;
}
```

Here is an example:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<String> meta = new ArrayList<>();
    meta.add("a");
    meta.add("c");
    A a = new A();
    a.setA("a");
    a.setB("b");
    a.setC("c");
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    getAllFields(fields,A.class);
    B b = new B();  // here you want to copy from a if meta contains
    fields.stream().filter(field -> meta.contains(field.getName()))
            .forEach(field -> {
                try{
                    Field temp = b.getClass().getDeclaredField(field.getName());
                    temp.setAccessible(true);
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    temp.set(b,field.get(a));
                }catch (Exception ex){
                }
            });
    System.out.println(b.getA());
    System.out.println(b.getB());
    System.out.println(b.getC());
}

public static List<Field> getAllFields(List<Field> fields, Class<?> type) {
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(type.getDeclaredFields()));

    if (type.getSuperclass() != null) {
        getAllFields(fields, type.getSuperclass());
    }
    return fields;
}


public static class A{
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    //getter setter
}

public static class B{
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    //getter setter
}
}
```

Comment: An example would be helpful.

Comment: check. example added.